# SunFire 100 RAID setup failed

Tags: raid, solaris-10

I have a SunFire 1000 and I would like to define the RAID. When I try to delete everything I get the error that there is not enough space:

```
# raidctl -C "0.0.0 0.1.0" -r 1 0
Creating RAID volume will destroy all data on spare space of member disks, proceed (ja/nein)? j
No enough disk space.
```

How can this be?

Format prints different geometries for the two disks:

```
# format -e
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <ATA-WDCWD3000GLFS-0-3V01 cyl 35769 alt 2 hd 128 sec 128>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/scsi@2/sd@0,0
       1. c0t1d0 <ATA-WDCWD3000GLFS-0-3V01 cyl 65533 alt 2 hd 16 sec 558>
          /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/scsi@2/sd@1,0
```

Comment: I would like to warn: do not use this hardware-based mirroring, it brings nothing but problems. Use either ZFS or SVM. As for the different geometries: like as not, one of the disks has already been accessed by this hardware RAID. This is just one of the mnirky things it does: make your disk look like a different geometry. Great fun when the disk fails and is replaced with one that still shows the original geometry. Another reason for avoiding the hardware mirror is that it disallows live upgrade - one of

Comment: @Karlchen9 How to fix the geometries? Live upgrade requires ZFS. It is possible to use RAID and ZFS.